# Humorous edit descriptions

Tags: discussion, edits, fun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you fill in an edit summary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/do-you-fill-in-an-edit-summary)

As of late, editing questions hasn't had the same pizazz as usual (though I still do it) So I began to put humorous edit descriptions such as *"Made OCD compliant"* and *"Pimp my question"*
Is it wrong to do this? When looking at most edits, they usually have no description, (and on these I wouldn't give a description normally).

So is it wrong to put a funny edit description instead of putting no description?

Also, if this is ok and other people have done it, then feel free to share your own funny edit descriptions :)

Comment: You haven't been on Meta very long, have you?

Comment: Nobody ever reads those edit thingies

Comment: you and random should, like, hang out together and stuff

Comment: sounds Like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/do-you-fill-in-an-edit-summary

Answer (score 10):

You say they're humorous, but looking over your recent activity pages says otherwise:

> [edited tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/44766/revisions)
>   [edited title; edited title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2548237/revisions)
>   [added 248 characters in body](https://serverfault.com/posts/128271/revisions)
>   [added 139 characters in body](https://superuser.com/posts/123231/revisions)

Yes, it is wrong to call these funny.

Answer (score 2):

[Ahem...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/44766/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to keep the description fairly succinct and accurate.  That said, I suspect most people don't look at the edit comments, so it won't do much damage.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it wrong to do this?

Nope.

> So is it wrong to put a funny edit description instead of putting no description?

Not at all.  The only time I bother explaining my edit is if I believe others might want to revert it, or may have questions about why.

Otherwise it's pretty much free rein.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever checked anything in to a version control repo? If so, you'll know that filling in those change logs can be very, very, very tedious. This is much the same.

Comment: Yes, and I've written funny change logs too before.. usually they actually half way pertain to what changed even!

Comment: I've seen some classic checkin comments. Nobody ever seemed to mind, especially if it's a simple change that anyone with a diff tool and half a brain can see what happened. Thankfully SO provides at least one of these tools.

Comment: That last sentence made me LOL

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only other people to read the edit comments are going to be other people who also want to make things "OCD compliant". So an explanation of what you've done in a humorous way is probably fine!