# When using my retag privilege, if I enter an edit reason, the system ignores it

Tags: bug, tags, edit-summary

With the recent change to remove the retag button and just use the edit screen, it appears that if you only edit the tags and submit the edit, any edit reason you added into the box gets completely ignored.

I edited [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/118641/revisions) (on Gaming.SE) and typed in the following edit reason:

> Added tag for specific game (this isn't a Nintendo question).

I was trying to explain *why* I edited the tags. Yet, to my surprise, the edit reason was recorded as simply "edited tags" after submission. Well, that sucks. Particularly because now my reasoning for changing the tags isn't present. I'm assuming that the system just detects that it was a *retag* and follows the same retag procedures as it used to follow (it would always just use that edit reason for a tag-only edit).

However, since all retags now have to go through the edit screen, and the *edit reason box is there*, wouldn't it make sense to go ahead and use that edit reason if a user took the time to fill one in, even if it's only a retag? It would be beneficial to at least *allow* users to explain their actions rather than just slapping a canonical "edited tags" note on every retag.

**Update:** Seems to be the opposite of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179465/retagging-without-the-edit-privilege-now-requires-an-edit-summary), though I didn't test if it lets me retag without entering something. It's even worse to force someone to enter a reason and then *not use it*.

Comment: The behaviour you explain in this post is mentioned in the last paragraph in Giles' post you link to... (although, yes, it shouldn't require a reason to start off with, and neither should it overwrite it with "edited tags").